# Access the Explorer from my application

Tags: tangle, client-library

In my application, I need to do some regular checks into the Tangle Explorer. I wonder if it's possible to access the Tangle Explorer directly from my application code, in order to automate the checks (via API or something like this).

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of requests (that the node's API does not provide)? Technically, the explorer runs JSON requests against `https://explorer-api.iota.org/`, but I doubt that this API is considered stable...

Comment: No request specification until now, since I'm planning my application (and not developing). So I understand that there exist some requests that can be done to the explorer directly from the application code.

Comment: If you want to find out what a transaction contains, or whether a transaction is already confirmed, or should be reattached (which are usual use cases for a humen to look at the explorer): There are node API calls for that, that every node (not only the "central" explorer) can answer. If you want to visit the explorer to validate that your transaction looks like it should (e.g. debug your code), an Explorer API will not help you either. So I don't see any need for an API to call the explorer, which is why I asked you what kind of requests you wanted to perform.